# Divide and Conquer a problem into a sub-problem to solve it efficiently

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, divide-and-conquer, proof-of-work

Assume that problem A cannot be solved in O(n^2) time. However, we can transform problem A into a problem B in O(n^2 log n) time, and then solve B, and finally transform the solution of B into the solution of A in O(n) time.

Prove or Disprove: The above approach shows that problem B cannot be solved asymptotically less than O(n^2) time.

---

My Answer->

```
Let time complexity (TC) of B be h(n). 
So overall complexity is maximum of(h(n), n²logn) which will be greater or equal
to n²logn greater than n² considering the highest polynomial term.

Ω(f(n)) ≥ { g(n) : there exists c > 0 and n0 such that g(n) ≤ c.f(n) for all n > n0 }.

Here f(n) is O(n2logn+n) and g(n) is O(n2logn) which satisfy the above condition at c>=1 and n0 = 0

(n^2 log n) < 1*(n^2logn+n) for all n > 0

So lower bound of solution B is g(n) i.e. O(n^2logn)

So B cannot be solved asymptotically less than O(n^2 log n) time

Therefore B cannot be solved asymptotically less than O(n^2) time
```

Comment: I am not getting the part when we convert the solution of B to A in O(n) time. Only this part is given. How do we find the time complexity of B from this problem @Yamar69

Comment: Your last sentence is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

The given information tells you absolutely nothing about the runtime of B.

As an example, let’s say the solution is a vector of N numbers which can be found in O(n^2 log n) but not in O(n^2), and let B be the problem “What was your input”. Solve the problem in O(n^2 log n), pass the solution to B, get it back in O(n), all consistent with the information you have.

Comment: When we reduce A to B, we are saying "If I could solve B in some model of computation, then I could solve A in that model, too", which means that B is at least as hard as A. But A could be easier. This is the basic theory i used.

Comment: According to the question, we reduce the problem of finding a solution of a vector of N number to a different problem, this conversion takes O(n^2 log n ) and the solve the reduced problem and again transform the solution of the reduced problem to the original problem, this other transformation takes o(n) time @gnasher729

Comment: And what if B takes O(n^10)? There _nothing_ you can say about B whatsoever.

Comment: @Swaray you are wrong. The time to reduce A->B plus the time to solve B plus the time to translate back to A is a lower bound for solving A but the time for the reduction is already much more than the given lower bound for A.

Comment: What I was suggesting is that if B is at least as hard as A. But A could be easier. So as A can't be done in O(n^2) B also can't be done in O(n^2)

Comment: I get what you are trying to tell. You are trying to go to solve A but the question revolves around time complexity of B @gnasher729

Comment: You say B is at least as hard as A - that's absolutely not true. I gave you a B that takes zero time to calculate.